# How to copy source files into stage/snap with snapcraft

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I'm trying to create a snapp from an app host on github (etherpad-lite).

When I launch the `snapcraft stage` command, snapcraft downloads all the files into the `parts/etherpad-lite/src` folder and then builds all that need to be built, and copies files into the `stage/bin` folder.

Now I need to copy some script from the source folder to the `stage/bin` folder.

How I can do that in snapcraft?

All the history is explained on the snap-app-devel ML : https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snappy-app-devel/2016-February/000611.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a copy plugin. So you can add a part that copies files into /bin

```
   <part-name>:
      plugin: copy
      source: <your source directory>
      files:
         <source path 1>: <destination path 1>
         <source path 2>: <destination path 2>
```

You can play around with that and check the result in the directories ./parts, ./stage and ./snap .

Comment: Thx @abbgrade, I didn't know that we could use the copy plugin like this :) I'll try

Comment: Is it possible to copy an entire folder ? or is it just file by file ?

Comment: Now that the `copy` plugin is deprecated how does one do this with the `dump` plugin? I get `Additional properties are not allowed ('files' was unexpected)` when I try this advice but with `plugin: dump`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dump plugin to copy files:

```
<part-name>:
   plugin: dump
   source: .
   stage:
      - <file1>
      - <file2>
```